Why doesn't render the flatlist a custom component which contains an Image in React-Native?
I made a custom component (Item), which should render an image and a text. The component renders the Text, but not the Image component.
Item component:
export default function Item({item}) {
    return (
    <View style={styles.cont}>
        <Image resizeMode="contain" source={require('../assets/products/iphone-1.jpeg')} style={styles.image} />
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    </View>)
}

If I try to render this component in a FlatList, then the Image won't be rendered, only the Text.
export default function HomeScreen() 
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Item item={items[0]} />
            <FlatList data={items} renderItem={({item}) => <Item item={item} />}/>
        </View>
    )
}

However, if I put the elements from the Item component directly into FlatList, then it works, like so:
export default function HomeScreen() {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('')

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Item item={items[0]} />
            <FlatList data={items} renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View style={styles.cont}>
                <Image resizeMode="contain" source={require('../assets/products/iphone-1.jpeg')} style={styles.image} />
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
            )}/>
        </View>
    )
}

Where do I have the mistake?

could you share the whole code, so we get the better idea where you are lagging.? I mean full code for HomeScreen.

That's the whole HomeScreen, there is just an array with items: one item has a couple of properties, like title, or image, but it is not necessary, since It doesn't matter if I use the Item component with the array, or just with hardcoded image path with require.  items=[{image: require('../assets/products/iphone-1.jpeg')}]

I think the part that @VinayUpadhyay might feel is missing is the styles. With Images styles can be pretty important. Quick thought I had are the require references? Is the item component in the same file or at least the same directory as the HomeScreen? If not that asset file url could be wrong.

You could use the onError prop to get further info on why the images arent rendering, but  its possible that you forgot to add a width and  height to styles.image in Item.js
